# SUPEE-10266 cannot be applied to 1.9.3.2

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, security, supee-10266

I am experiencing issues patching the new SUPEE 10266 on Magento 1.9.3.2

The files where the hunks start failing have not been modified by me. Anyone else experiencing the same issue or have managed to resolve this, please share.

```
$ sh PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-09-13-06-38-58.sh
PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-09-13-06-38-58.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-09-13-06-38-58.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-09-13-06-38-58.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-09-13-06-38-58.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-09-13-06-38-58.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.3.2_v1-2017-09-13-06-38-58.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Session.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Notification/Grid/Renderer/Notice.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Form/Container.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/CustomerController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/QueueController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Newsletter/TemplateController.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 267 (offset -17 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 686 (offset -25 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Abstract.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 251 (offset 16 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 90 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php
Hunk #1 succeeded at 135 (offset -1 lines).
Hunk #2 succeeded at 162 (offset -1 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml
Hunk #1 succeeded at 459 (offset -8 lines).
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Rss/Helper/Data.php
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order/Item/Collection.php
checking file app/code/core/Zend/Serializer/Adapter/PhpCode.php
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 120.
Hunk #2 FAILED at 151.
2 out of 2 hunks FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/file.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 58.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login-simple.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 58.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 46.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 53.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
checking file app/design/install/default/default/template/install/create_admin.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 66.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv
checking file downloader/template/login.phtml
Hunk #1 FAILED at 35.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED
```

Comment: Check against magereport.com just to make sure you got all previous patches installed.

Comment: check app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml with core any code changes in this file. if changes available you missed some patches.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have to check that all previous patches are installed or not. You can test  it from https://www.magereport.com/
If patches are missing then install them one by one and at last try to install 10266 patch.

Answer (score 0):

I checked thoroughly that all the patches, till date, had been applied, yet I was getting the conflicts.

Hence restored the conflicting files from 1.9.3.4 from herein - https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/releases/tag/1.9.3.4

Thereafter the patch was applied smoothly.