# Magento Patch SUPEE-10266 how to apply?

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-10266

How to install the most recent security path?

Is there any particular way to do it?

Getting a lot of errors: "Skipping patch ...... 1 out of 1 ignored ..."

Is it because is already patched or ...?

My Magento version is 1.9.2.3.

```
checking file 
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking
```

... just a part of it.

Problem already solved.
Don't need to comment anymore ;)

Comment: Your error indicates a mismatch of the file checking, the line above 'hunk failed' should indicate which file. Please paste your error for further assistance

Comment: Funny thing is that I just installed a new Magento instance and ..... missing files ? Isn't that weird ? :)

Comment: Need some more clear information. you are install from magento root path?

Comment: Yes of course and of course chmod+x patch.sh, then ./ patch.sh from Magento root. I did it before, other patches installed without any problems.

Comment: Hmm, have you checked your patches.list?

Comment: What do you mean do I checked my patches list ? All previous patches installed. Regardless if it is a fresh magento installed, I just installed all the secuu's

Comment: In app/etc/applied.patches.list it has a list of installed patches, you could use this to determine if the patch was previously applied

Comment: there is nothing about 10266 :) other patches yes.

Comment: It seems like there is a lot of bugs in a patch code ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-10266 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193279/security-patch-supee-10266-possible-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI mine was it didnt have this PRIOR to patch

input type="text" class="input-text no-display" name="dummy" id="dummy"

basically patch is switching from above to

input type="password" class="input-text no-display" name="dummy" id="dummy"

but for some reason some templates did not have this

Answer (score 1):

However if the patch script not found files to patch it should continue with the other ones and at the end patch should be applied and displayed as applied - eventually should display additional message about missing files IF those files were important or required etc but not just stop proceeding.

Finally I managed to install all the patches including 10266 - to achieve this I changed a code and also removed lines pointing to the non existing files.
Checked against the security issues and everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can verify the patch status on most vulnerabilities via https://magereport.com. It will tell you what is needing to be patched and what doesn’t. That should answer any question on patch status you have.

You can also check webroot/app/etc/applied.patches.list or similar and see whether the appropriate supee number is listed or not