# USPS Patch SUPEE-10336 - Possible issues?

Tags: magento-1, patches, usps

A new USPS patch has been released for Magento 1:

https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2070

What common issues do you have to watch out for when applying this patch?

> -This patch addresses USPS method name changes starting Sep 1, 2017 - Added Sep 11, 2017

A topic like this exists for [SUPEE-10266](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193279/security-patch-supee-10266-possible-issues), which is newer but has a lower patch number.
We discovered two problems and one fix for this less known official patch. That is why we created this topic. To help the community with what we found, and to hope to get answers for problems with certain older Magento versions.

Answer (score 2):

The patch description (and filename) says for Magento 1.8.0.0 you should use patch file

```
PATCH_SUPEE-10336_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2017-09-11-02-27-31.sh
```

We at [MageHost.pro](https://magehost.pro) discovered this does not work, however this one does work:

```
PATCH_SUPEE-10336_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2017-09-11-02-26-23.sh
```

Comment: So you decided to use PATCH_SUPEE-10336_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2017-09-11-02-26-23.sh to apply for Magento 1.8.0.0?

Comment: Yes indeed, that is what we did. This solved the issue during our tests on vanilla Magento installs.

Answer (score 0):

I did not yet get the patch working for:

```
 Magento 1.6.0.0
 Magento 1.6.1.0
 Magento 1.6.2.0
```

I guess this is caused by `SUPEE-7616` not working for these versions.