# SUPEE-10266 and SUPEE-10348

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, security

I have a client's site that is currently using Magento 1.9.1.0 and need to apply the latest patches. I've applied both 10266 and 10336 (in that order) - all good. However on the description for 10266, it states the following:

> SUPEE-10266 for Magento Commerce (Enterprise Edition) includes a fix
>   for a functional issues MPERF-9685, related to checkout with a zero
>   order amount. This fix is not included in release 1.14.3.6. However,
>   in some cases, SUPEE-10266 can cause issues in the checkout process.
>   Specifically, if a customer enables the Add gift options checkbox
>   during checkout, the checkout process will not progress beyond the
>   payments step. Magento released a fix for this issue as a new patch
>   SUPEE-10348, that needs to be installed on top of SUPEE-10266.

I can't find the download for 10348 anywhere, and I do not have Magento support, so how do I install this patch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-10266 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193279/security-patch-supee-10266-possible-issues)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SUPEE-10348 is only for Enterprise Edition. not for Community Edition. 
No need to apply SUPEE-10348 for CE. 1.9.1.0.

---

SUPEE 10348 is Giftcard Fixes.

**For reference:** 
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ee1.14_release-notes.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - clearly I can't read properly!