# Magento 1.9 Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, dashboard

After new **magento 1.9** installation when I am login to the **admin panel** there is a fine flow.

After that if I am opening admin panel on other tab like:

> www.example.com/admin

**It is showing error on dashboard**

> Invalid Secret Key. Please refresh the page.

[image]

Comment: First of all enable formkey validation.
Then check web/cookie/cookie_domain and web/cookie/cookie_path to either be correct or empty

Comment: formkey validation is enabled.
web/cookie/cookie_domain set to mydomain.com
web/cookie/cookie_path set to /
But still facing error

Comment: Can you post the settings you have at General/Web/Session Cookie Management and General/Web/Session Validation Settings ?

Comment: Here it is: https://www.screencast.com/t/GdRnK2ucNM please ignore example.com, I have changed it just for demo

Comment: Use HTTP Only = No is a security risk. I'd reccomend you changed it back on. 
This is still probably a cookie issue. Have you tried logging in from another browser or computer?

Comment: Yes I have tried it with different accounts, different browsers and different computers, but still same issue :(

Comment: Do you have a staging site? If so, make sure your cookie domain for each site is set respective to it's full domain/sub-domain. e.g. `www.domain.com` and `staging.domain.com`

Comment: @shaikh.mushoaib did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this issue on EE 1.14, and was provided SUPEE-10358 to fix (which it did!).

The patch updates one line in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php`

In the preDispatch() method, replace
`if ($_keyErrorMsg != ''){`
with
`if (!$_isValidFormKey) {` (around line 189).

I haven't tried it yet in CE, but Action.php is the same in CE 1.9, so I'm hoping this same patch will do the trick.