# M1 patch SUPEE-10266 - Magereport shown as "not patched"

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-10266

I am currently installing 10266 on multiple sites, and when running the patch via cli:

```
sh PATCH_SUPEE-10266_CE_1.9.2.4_v1-2017-09-13-06-37-37.sh
```

I receive:

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
```

Perfect. However when I run the sites through magereport.com, 10266 is shown as "not patched", even after providing the backend url. Is this a case of magereport requiring certain permissions to function? If so, which ones?

And yes, I flushed the cache :)

Comment: i have install this patch on one of my site and magereport shows it installed

Comment: Do you have a custom admin theme?

Comment: @seanbreeden There is a custom admin theme in use, though it's not something I'm familiar with as we inherited this from another developer(!). There were no problems  when I checked applied-patches.list, so at a bit of a loss as to whether it's patched or not.

Comment: For 10266, if you have a custom admin theme you have to ensure that the patch runs on your custom files as well. It will require some manual changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Security Patch SUPEE-10266 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193279/security-patch-supee-10266-possible-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For further info on this patch see [Security Patch SUPEE-10266 - Possible issues?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193279/security-patch-supee-10266-possible-issues)

Check that you have no custom admin theme files overwriting the patched files for SUPEE-8788. The admin files affected are as follows:

```
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/file.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/customer/tab/view.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/login.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/notification/toolbar.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login-simple.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/oauth/authorize/form/login.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/resetforgottenpassword.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/history.phtml
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/info.phtml
```

There are some minor changes in these files that need to be applied to your custom template files in order for MageReport to confirm the patch is in place.

Comment: Thank you Matt. Yes, we did have a custom admin theme (we inherited the site from another dev!). I installed the patch on a fresh Mag install and ran a few diffs to find the changes required.